# Android Cocos2d Xoom Image Pixelation Issue

Tags: android, game-engine, cocos2d-android

I am working with Android Cocos2d Ref. (http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1).

All the things working fine with Standard Device, Samsung Tablet with (1024*600 Resolution).
Problem starts with Motorola Xoom (1280*800).

Is the Cocos2d not supporting Image Resolution higher that 1024?

Let me know If there is any other alternate Cocos2d source.

I have attached 3 Images..
rainbow.jpg - Original Image
[image: Original Image]

cocos_github_issue.png - Image that is rendering on device by using (http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android)
[image]

cocos_lib_issue.png - Image that is rendering on device by using (http://github.com/ZhouWeikuan/cocos2d)
[image]

Comment: i am to game development in android using Cocos2d framework .. could u suggest some samples and books to developed my skills... i didn`t find any major samples books form net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the Cocos2d not supporting Image Resolution higher that 1024?

That's likely correct. On ios it's not upto 2048 on most devices, but older devices are still limited to 1024 max size. I think this is an OpenGL limitation rather than Cocos2d. OpenGL 1.1 and lower are, I believe, limited to 1024 * 1024 textures.

If you can call opengl calls directly, try the Java equivalent of this:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, &result);
```